# Move an item in a list

Tags: jquery

I need to remove an element in my list and move it to another position (pos 10).

I use:

```
$('.my-list').eq(11).before($('.icon').detach());
```

But it's not working. The below works by itself, so I am targeting it right.

```
$('.icon').detach()
```

Comment: index start with zero so use `eq(10)`

Comment: `.detach()` removes the element from DOM so when you execute that, there's no longer any object to `.before()`

Comment: You don't need to call `detach()`, it will automatically detach it from the old place when moving it.

Comment: Can you make a [stack snippet](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: .my-list is really selector? every li has that class?

Comment: @nevermind seems right. Maybe it should be `$('.my-list li').eq(11)`. This is why you need to post a more complete question.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, it is always easier with HTML. Otherwise - try and guess game....

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `.detach()` at all. Just bear in mind that you inserting before `n-1`, not `n+1`, as counting begins at `0`, **and position `n+1` may not even exist.** *For example, if you have 11 items on your list, and you wish to move the first to position 10. The lowest index is `0` and the highest is `10` (or `11-1`). In this case, position `12` (or `11+1`) is out of range, and the code targeting that position would do nothing.*

```js
//move first element to position 4
$('li').eq(4).before( $('li').eq(0) );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks but does not answer the question.

Comment: Can you provide your markup and code that's not working. It shouldn't take long for you to post your complete HTML and JS, should it, @panthro? **How many positions are there? 10?**

Comment: 100000s of positions.

Comment: Thanks, that quite helpful. **If you think there's too much code to post -- people here are willing to help you, but you're not willing to help them help you -- isn't there a way to create a minimal demo to show the issue you're experiencing?**